# Как привязать программу на Python к железу

Tags: python, python-3.x, защита

Необходимо защитить программу от копирования путём привязки к железу. Как это можно сделать на Питоне? Скрипт скомпелирован в exe файл, если это имеет значение.

Comment: Можете запросить информацию о процессоре (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyCPUID), запросить информацию о серийниках накопителей (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193514/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-using-python), добавить MAC адрес и посолить моделью GPU, если применимо. Однако, серьезным взломщикам это станет крайне простой преградой, если вообще хоть какой-нибудь, а легитимным пользователям может доставить много головняка. Не надо так.

Comment: Если скрипт компилирован в бинарник с помощью Нютки, то хакеры будут пять лет ломать код! :)